# Why the command does not run on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET 3.5 (C#) application, but interestingly it does not run on **Windows XP**, but on windows 7 works well.
My code is :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

CmdData.FillDataSet(ref ds, "Select * from T_User");

bool admin = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<long>("Id") == 1;
```

The error occurs on the **third line** and show this window

[image]

Details error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
>     'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0,     Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or    one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

When the following code to replace the third line, my app works **without error**:

```
bool admin = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString().Equals("1");
```

I do not want to use this command because I need the name of the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't have .net 3.5 installed on the xp machine.

Comment: ".net 2 sp2" and ".net 4" is installed on win xp.I should I install 3.5?

Comment: then target your framework to .net 4 in project properties@javadaskari